# Bootstrapping quantiles from an estimated binary outcome

Tags: modeling, bootstrap, binary-data, uncertainty

I am trying to predict a binary outcome that is unobserved but I have made bootstrap estimations of its value. As a result I have bootstrapped training data where the outcome for the same observation can change between iterations.

The outcomes relate to area populations. I want to calculate the quantiles around the mean of the population that are positive

If my model was 100% accurate I could bootstrap the probability of the area being positive directly. However, through cross-validation I know that the model has error.

To calculate the distribution I use the predicted probability of an area being positive and multiply its probability of flipping by the cross validation accuracy of the model, (See equation below). I then bootstrap those probabilities to find the estimate of the total positive population.

$$\textbf{P}(\text{flip})=(\textbf{P}(\text{Vote %})-0.5)*\textbf{P}(\text{Model correct})+0.5$$

**Is this a reasonable approach?**

An alternative would be to treat the probability outcomes as a regression and then do some sort of bootstrapping on that..

The code below runs in R as an explanation of my process

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(BootPercent = c(1,0.95,0.1,0.95,0.0,0.01), #percentage of models that predict positive
           BootVote = c(1,1,0,1,0,0),  #majority vote outcome
           Population = c(100,300, 200, 200, 300, 100)) #Population in each area

#function that samples flip probability
GetEmpDistrib <- function(df, samps = 1000, ModelAccuracy = 1){
   1:6 %>% map(~{
  #calculate flip chance given model accuracy
  SampleProb <- (df$BootPercent[.x]-0.5)*ModelAccuracy+0.5

  sample(1:0, samps, replace = T, prob = c(SampleProb, 1-SampleProb)) %>%
      data.frame(Outcome = .)*df$Population[.x]
  }) %>% bind_cols() %>%
    mutate(totals = rowSums(.))
}

#When the model is 100% accurate
set.seed(56435)
Res1 <- GetEmpDistrib(df, samps = 10000, ModelAccuracy = 1) 

quantile(Res1$totals,  probs = c(0.05,0.95)) #quantiles for 90% of data
Res1 %>% ggplot(aes(x = totals)) + geom_density() # plot of data

#when the model is only 60% accurate
set.seed(56435)
Res2 <- GetEmpDistrib(df, samps = 1000, ModelAccuracy = 0.6) 
quantile(Res2$totals,  probs = c(0.05,0.95))
Res2 %>% ggplot(aes(x = totals)) + geom_density()
```